# How do I execute a SQL statement with parameters in ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to execute SQL statement with paraemeters in ServiceStack ormlite

```cs
String.Format("SELECT OBJECT_ID(@name)", name);
```

I want the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the POCO result you can use:

```
List<Person> results = db.SqlList<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age < @age", new { age=50});
```

Reference: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SqlScalar<T>` where `T` is `int`. Then simply pass an anonymous object with your parameter.

```cs
int result = db.SqlScalar<int>("SELECT OBJECT_ID(@name)", new { name = "SomeName" });
```

to select a `List<T>` of POCO type rather than an `int` you can use:

```
var results = db.SqlList<User>("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = @name", new { name = "SomeName" });
```

You can [read more here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#using-typed-sqlexpression-in-custom-sql-apis) in the official documentation examples.

Hope this helps.